# My Angular 8 Resolver don't evokes. Page loading without getting data

Tags: angular, typescript, resolver

In my Angular 8 Project i have a 'route' like this.

app-routing.module.ts (with routes and resolvers) -> member-edit.resolver.ts (overrided resolve method with access to accountService) -> member-edit.component.ts (trying to load data from resolver in ngOnInit())

My Resolver don't evokes, so I don't recive any data in ngOnInit()

I have the same code in Angular 6 project and it works fine. I can not find any solution to force it to work in my Angular 8 project.

I just want too use resolvers in my Angular 8 project to load data to component..

I tried to downgrade my Angular 8 project but i wasn't succesful. I had some problems with it, and plenty of errors. Otherwise it wouldn't be a great solution.

If I invoke to my service to get data its working well. But when I using my resolver I cannot recive any data.

I notice there is some changes in Angular 8 -> '@angular/router' compering this with Angular 6 but I can't find any solution to fix it. (especially ActivatedRoute)

My Angular 8 [ng v]: (not working resolver)

```
    Angular CLI: 8.1.3
    Node: 10.16.0
    OS: win32 x64
    Angular: 8.1.3
    ... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    ... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
    ... router

    Package                           Version
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect         0.801.3
    @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.801.3
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.801.3
    @angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.801.3
    @angular-devkit/core              8.1.3
    @angular-devkit/schematics        8.1.3
    @angular/.compiler-cli.MODULES    <error>
    @angular/cdk                      8.1.2
    @angular/material                 8.1.2
    @ngtools/webpack                  8.1.3
    @schematics/angular               8.1.3
    @schematics/update                0.801.3
    rxjs                              6.4.0
    typescript                        3.4.5
    webpack                           4.35.2
```

My Angular 6 [ng v]: (resolver have data)

```
    Angular CLI: 6.0.8
    Node: 10.16.0
    OS: win32 x64
    Angular: 6.1.10
    ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    ... http, language-service, platform-browser
    ... platform-browser-dynamic, router

    Package                           Version
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
    @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
    @angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
    @angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
    @angular/cli                      6.0.8
    @ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
    @schematics/angular               0.6.8
    @schematics/update                0.6.8
    rxjs                              6.0.0
    typescript                        2.7.2
    webpack                           4.8.3
```

Ok, so lets start..

So focus on the 3 files:

```
member-edit.component.ts
member-edit.resolver.ts
app-routing.module.ts
```

"member-edit.component.ts:"

On the beggining I have member-edit.component.ts and I will focus on the 
ngOnInit() method, look's like this:

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      secondName: ['', ],
      surname: ['', Validators.required]
    }, {});

     this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Check route resolver data');
      this.account = data.account;
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.account);
    });
    }
```

My member-edit.resolver.ts looking like this:

```
        @Injectable()
    export class MemberEditResolver implements Resolve<User> {
        constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router, private alertify: AlertifyService, private authService: AuthService) {}

        resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User> {
            return this.userService.getUser(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid).pipe(
                catchError(error => {
                    this.alertify.error('Problem with retriving your data.');
                    this.router.navigate(['/members']);
                    return of(null); // null ale jako observer
                })
            );
        }
    }
```

And routing file:

```
        const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      {
        path: '', // localhost:4200/members etc..
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
          { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
          { path: 'thesis', component: ThesisComponent },
          { path: 'promoters', component: PromotersComponent },
          { path: 'groups', component: GroupsComponent },
          { path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent },
          { path: 'help', component: HelpComponent },
          { path: 'adminPanel', component: AdminPanelComponent },
          { path: 'member/edit', component: MemberEditComponent },
          // { path: 'members', component: MemberListComponent, resolve: { users: MemberListResolver } },
          // { path: 'members/:id', component: MemberDetailComponent, resolve: { user: MemberDetailResolver } },
          {
            path: 'member/edit',
            component: MemberEditComponent,
            resolve: { account: MemberEditResolver }
          }
        ]
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
      providers: [MemberEditResolver]
    })

    export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I'm a bit depressed becouse I have no idea what should I more. Everything working well on Angular 6, but here on 8 my resolver don't load any data so i don't have anything in:

```
this.account = data.account;
```

for debug purpose I used console.log and this one reciving to my console object only with __ proto __

What should I do to load data from resolver?

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I could try, gimme a sec

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I have some problems with stackblitz, could I send you link to my repo where you could find my problem?